# Using HWIOAuthBundle and LexikJWT at the same time

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle, lexikjwtauthbundle

As the title suggests, I'm going to use Facebook,Google and GitHub authentication alongside JWT authenticator (LexikJWT).

Before starting, I want to know how can I use them? is it possible to use both of them to protect APIs?

If yes, what sort of configurations should my security have? Assuming that I'm using the default configurations.

here is the current `security.yml`:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    acl:
        connection: default

    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: affirmative

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SALES_NOTIFICATIONS: [ ROLE_SALES_NOTIFICATIONS ]
        # FULL CONTROL
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        # Disabling the security for the web debug toolbar, the profiler and Assetic.
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
        admin:
            pattern:            /admin(.*)
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
                success_handler: admin_success_handler
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
            anonymous:          true

        # Custom firewall for api area
        api_login:
            pattern:  ^/api/auth
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: fos_userbundle
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/auth/check
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api/v\d+\.\d+/
            methods: [ POST, PUT ]
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator

        api_doc:
            pattern: ^/api/doc
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
        # -> end custom configuration

        # default login area for standard users

        # This firewall is used to handle the public login area
        # This part is handled by the FOS User Bundle
        main:
            pattern:             .*
            context:             user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:             true
            anonymous:          true

    access_control:
        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Admin login page needs to be access without credential
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Secured part of the site
        # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
        # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
        - { path: ^/assets/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/uploads/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
        - { path: ^/user/, role: [ROLE_USER] }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/auth, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/auth/me, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
- { path: ^/api/v\d+\.\d+/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

I'm thinking, using both of them as a security provider will lead to errors. is it right?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think using HWIOAuthBundle and LexikJWTBundle on the same project will lead to errors.

You api_login firewall will authenticate your api users while your admin firewall will authenticate your backoffice users.

Since your URL patterns are correctly congigured you should not encounter problems.